# How to decrease app currency (like game currency) on users activity?

Tags: java, android, rewardedvideoad

I have made an app in which there are app currency (like coins in games) and i have implemented reward video ads in it. I have some items in the activity which can be downloaded by the user. I want to decrease the app currency when the user clicks to download the items and when the coins become 0 I want to alert the user to watch a reward video to get some coins. How can this be done?

Comment: This question is quite impossible to answer without more informations. What have you done until now? Can you show us some code? Can you explain where your problem is exactly?

Comment: @eXodiquas i have only implemented the reward video ads. nothing more. My problem is I want to decrease the coins by an amount(say 5) when the user tries to download something from within the app

Answer (score 0):

As a user pointed out, we need more information to help you solve this.

If the currency is an `int variable` within an activity, everytime the user hits the "buy" button you decrement the variale, say  currency = currency - 5 and `if(currency<=0) { [show the dialog to watch an ad] }`, if the currency is stored in a database as it should be then you retrieve the value of the currency for that player ID, decrement it by the value of your choice and update the row with the new value.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to implement the functionality in my app. Here's how i did

```
private TextView mText;
private int coinCount;
mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.money);
    coinCount = 0;
    mText.setText(" " + coinCount);


Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buynow);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (coinCount <= 29) {
                //if(coinCount <30) {
                new MaterialStyledDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Not Enough Coins")
                        .setDescription("Watch the Ad To Get 10 coins")
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_money)
                        .withIconAnimation(true)
                        .withDialogAnimation(true)
                        .withDarkerOverlay(true)
                        .setHeaderColor(R.color.color)
                        .setPositiveText("Get some coins")
                        .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                                mRewardedVideoAd.show();
                            }
                        })

                        .show();

            } else {
                    coinCount = coinCount - 30;
                    mText.setText(String.valueOf(coinCount));

                }

        }
    });
```